# When I touch axis x, cylinder rotate but always same direction(Android)

Tags: android, rotation, unity-game-engine, touch, axis

As I sad problem when I touch axis x, cylinder rotate but always positive y axis. I want to rotate negative and positive rotation on y axis.

This is the my script code :

```
  function Update () {
if (Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Moved) {
var pos : Vector3 = Input.GetTouch(0).position;
pos.y=0;
pos.z=0;
pos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(pos);
transform.Rotate(0,pos.x,0);

}
}
```

Thanks for helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
transform.Rotate(0,pos.x,0);
```

It always rotates the same direction because you're always rotating it in the same direction. If you want it to rotate in a different direction, you need to change one of the arguments in your `Rotate` function. Currently you're only rotating on the y axis. I don't know what exactly your requirements are for this though so I can't help beyond that.

```
transform.Rotate(x, y, z);
```

Comment: Thanks your reply I want to rotate y axis I can't rotate negative y axis always rotate positive y axis.